# Define custom HashSet in Scala?

Tags: scala, hashset, scala-collections

Basically I have three variables a,b and c. The variables have certain relationship among them. I need to store the variables in a HashSet so that each variable will be different and there wont be any redundancy.

**Java way:**

In java I just create a custom class, override hash and equal methods in that custom class and I will be done.

```
HashSet<CustomClass> hSet = new HashSet<CustomClass>();
```

**Scala way (Scala newbie):**

[Introduction to Sets and Maps for Scala](https://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/scala-part-3-sets-maps/)

Here I am confused to choose between a trait , class and an object. Obviously at the first look I cannot have trait and class assigned to a var / val (Please let me know if the above can be done). So object is the way to go.

```
object State {
    var a: Int;
    var b: Int;
    var c: Int;
}
```

**Question 1:**
**How should I define a custom (class/trait/object) HashSet?**

Normal HashSet declaration in Scala: `var hSet = new HashSet();`

**Question 2:
How to assign value to the new object? for example,**

```
var newState = State;
newState.a = 100;
hSet.add(newState);
```

**Error : type mismatch; found : Int(100) required: Int.type**

Thank you

Comment: The simplest and most common way is to use `case class` for your elements.

Comment: I am new to Scala. Thanks I will look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: the Scala way is the same as the Java way. That said, case classes can help you by automatically constructing a valid hash and equals methods (and `toString` and `apply` for that matter). It goes like this:

```
case class MyClass(myInt: Int, myString: String)
val hSet = new mutable.HashSet[MyClass]();
hSet += MyCLass(2, "foo")
```

Note that HashSets have type parameters, just as in Java. For immutable sets the syntax varies a little, but comming from Java this will feel easier.

Also, when you define an `object` you are basically defining a class with a single instance (a singleton pattern). This is clearly not what you want here.